# Javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: String.formCharCode is not a function"

Tags: javascript

could someone help me on this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: String.formCharCode is not a function.

Issue still visible when I use `var chars = String.formCharCode(65);` instead of old one.. I really don't know why, I checked the `String.fromCharCode(num)` from w3school, but nothing useful, could some kind person help me, thanks a lot! my code as below showing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>track_keyboard_input</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            var type = "Event type: " + event.key;
            var keyPressed = "Keyboard value: " + event.keyCode;
            var chars = "Keyboard character: " + String.formCharCode(event.keyCode);

            // var chars = String.formCharCode(65); //also failed when use this one.

            console.log(event);
            var result = '<br>' + type + '<br>' + keyPressed + '<br>' + chars;
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = result;
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Press a key:</p><br> 
<span id="output2"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the console, start typing `String.` and see what pops up as autosuggestions. You'll see `fromCharCode`; notice your typo. Or select that, then copy and paste from the console into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you spelled .fromCharCode wrong.

```
var chars = String.formCharCode(65); //also failed when use this one.
```

should be

```
var chars = String.fromCharCode(65);
```

Comment: This is precisely what the "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or *a simple typographical error*." close reason is for.